# Can I save a Word Document that has been "Compared" without the Formatting Changes

Tags: microsoft-word

When using the compare feature in Word, I would like to select that the formatting changes not show then save the document.  When the next user opens the document, I would like for it to open without the formatting changes.  Is there a way to do this?  I would like for the user to be able to open the "compared" redline document and have it NOT show the formatting changes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my Microsoft Word 2010, I found that the following can achieve your goal:

1. Select the "Review" menu, and deselect "Reviewing Pane".
2. Change the "Final: Show Markup" selection to "Original" (or "Final" if that is what you are looking for.)
3. Close the two compare windows on the right.
4. Save your document.

Answer (score 0):

One technique is to go to tracking->show markup and deselect comments and insertions/deletions:

[image]

You can then accept all changes shown:
[image]

If you want it to not track changes while you make changes, you can set that under tracking options:
[image]